# How to read data from serial using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem when trying to print some gps data coming from a serial port using python.

the code that is supposed to print the data:

```
while True:
    serialInst.write('at+cgpsinfo\r'.encode('utf-8'))
    sleep(1)
    packet = serialInst.readline()
    packet_decodificat = packet.decode('utf-8')
    print(packet_decodificat)
```

but this is the output:

```
OK



                        <-- here is printing an empty line where the gps data should've been...
```

[image: output]

this is the output when I'm using the tool from simcom to send AT commands:

```
2021-05-11 19:18:15:065[Send->]at+cgpsinfo
2021-05-11 19:18:15:073[Recv<-]

OK

2021-05-11 19:18:15:790[Recv<-]

+CGPSINFO: 478.215547,N,2734.862213,E,100521,161816.0,80.4,0.0,0.0
```

I'm new to python so there might be an obvious mistake in my code that I'm not aware of :D

Comment: You're only making one attempt to read a line of data after sending the command - but the response is split over two lines.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue, the `readline()` is inside a `while True:` loop. I wonder, though, is the `sleep(1)` necessary? `readline()` should wait until there is input, so I expect the sleep is pointless.

Comment: Oops, sorry, just read the code again: I think @jasonharper has it right. Inside your loop, after you send your query, you should try to read all the input available, not just one line. If you know the response is always going to be two lines, two calls to `readline()` might work, but otherwise you might end up in a deadlock. You might need to look for a non-blocking read that can return what data is available right now.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the issue <3